# stymied by Facebook Feed Dialogue with iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook

I'm working on an iPhone app from which I want the user to be able to post a photo and caption to his or her Facebook wall.  I started  with the following code, which I modified from code I got from `developers.facebook.com`.

```
UIImage *pic = [self createImage];
NSString *kAppId=@"xxxxxxxxxxx0507";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kAppId, @"app_id",
    pic, @"picture",@"My Haiku", @"name",@"Maybe he'll love me if I give him a haiku....",@"message",nil];
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

This gave me an `undeclared identifier 'facebook'` error, so after poking around some more I downloaded the iOS Facebook SDK.  However, I've been stymied by the following installation instructions at `developers.facebook.com`:

--quote--

If you create an iOS app that has Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) enabled then you should use a static library version of the iOS Facebook SDK instead of dragging in the files from the src folder. The latest release of the iOS Facebook SDK includes a shell script you can run to build the static library. You would do this through the command line by calling the build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh build script found under the scripts directory, for example:

```
% ~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh
```

This will create the static library under the /lib/facebook-ios-sdk folder (e.g. ~/facebook-ios-sdk/lib/facebook-ios-sdk). You may then drag the facebook-ios-sdk folder into the app Xcode project to include the iOS Facebook SDK static library.

--end quote--

I don't know what a shell script is or what a scripts directory is.  I tried running the line of code in the Terminal, but got a `no such job` message.  Where and how do I run the "shell script [I] can run to build the static library"?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First Download the iOS facebook sdk.
Then unzip the zip file and you will have a folder open it. Inside it you will have a folder with name Scripts open it and you will find a script file "build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh" Now open the terminal [Launchpad --> Utilities --> terminal] and drag drop this shell script file to the terminal and press enter it will generate a folder With name Lib into your unziped downloaded folder now Open your Xcode project and right click on the top of your project naivgator right click --> Add files to "Project" now navigate to your facebook sdk and add the folder inside Lib folder which is just created.. Thats it :)

Comment: This is for older version of facebook ios sdk FBConnect but they have advanced the sdk and new version 3.0 seems very different.

Comment: Thanks so much--but, alas, when I download the SDK and open it there's no script file "build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh".  The quest continues....

Comment: (Unless what you're saying, naveen, is that this isn't what I should be trying to do at all, in which case I'm flummoxed.)

Comment: @JoelDerfner give me your email id i'll mail you the sdk with static one

Comment: it's joel@joelderfner.com.  Thanks so very much.